# phpmyadmin - update current timestamp without updating values in the row

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I use PHP to update the particular row..  I have a column called "last updated" which I created via phpmyadmin, like this

```
 type => "datetime", default => current time stamp, on update =>current timestamp
```

"last updated" column's time gets updated when PHP actually changes any value in the row, but sometimes PHP updates the row but the values are same, in that case, last_update column remain same, I want to change its time even no value get changed

is there any option available in phpmyadmin or i have to update "last updated" column via php code

Comment: You could always not have it auto-update and update it manually in the update operations. MySQL seems to be using a post-update trigger but no changes means that a row is not updated so it doesn't count as an update. You can confirm this by looking at the "affected rows" value after the update.

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657189/update-mysql-table-with-same-values-and-still-get-a-timestamp-update

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
type => "datetime", default => NULL, on update =>current timestamp
```